# How to evaluate the integral $\int_C f(z) \, dz$ where $C$ is the unit circle centered at $0$ and $f(z) = \frac{1}{e^z-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I thought I could use residue theory. I first get the first few terms of the Laurent series as
$$ \frac{1}{e^z-1} = \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{z}{12} - \frac{z^3}{720} + \cdots$$

But then I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach it as I don't know where to take this next. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: If you parameterise the contour by $z(\theta)=e^{i\theta}, \; 0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$ it is easy to see that the integral is equal to $2\pi i$.

Comment: This would make the integral then $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{i\theta}}{e^{e^{i\theta}}-1}d\theta$? This seems almost more confusing to me than the original...

Comment: If you prefer, the residue theorem is "easier". You need only show that the residue at the origin is equal to one.

Comment: I see. Well, we have that the residue at the origin is equal to one given the Laurent series representation above. Since $z_0 = 0$, we can get the residue $b$ from $\frac{b}{z-z_0} = \frac{1}{z}$, hence $b = 1$. Is this a valid understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already answered your question with the expansion.
$$
\int_C\frac{1}{e^z - 1}dz = 2\pi i\sum\text{Res}_{z = z_j}
$$
From the expansion, you have found a simple pole at the origin so 
$$
\int_C\frac{1}{e^z - 1}dz = 2\pi i \lim_{z_j\to 0}(z - z_j)\frac{1}{z} =2\pi i
$$